# SOT23 package jumper

Tags: pcb, altium, replacement, jumper, sot23

I’m replacing some components on existing PCB, and I need to replace transistor in SOT23 package with a jumper. Problem is that none of the standard jumper packages are not suitable for more than a prototype, I would need exactly jumper in configuration shown on a picture. Alternatively I can use resistor of at least 250 mW in the same configuration. I’m  replacing voltage controller on that spot, and placing resistor in series with it, but I would not like to change PCB.
Does anyone have some suggestion what I could do here?

[image]

Comment: Would a 0-ohm resistor work? You could probably find a package size that would be close enough.

Comment: Strange. How many already made PCBs are you trying to save?

Comment: Also consider whether a diode would be feasible here; I'm pretty sure I've seen SOT-23 diodes that use pins 1 and 2 as the anode and pin 3 as the cathode, or vice versa. The fact that it shorts pins 1 and 2 might mean it does what you need, as long as the diode junction isn't a problem.

Comment: I once tried to look into something like this. I think there are packaging houses that will make this for you but I am not sure if it is economical to do it. Especially if you don't have high volume.

Comment: https://topline.tv/jumper.html#SOT23

Comment: Dual diode with common anode and one leg lifted would work. But it isn't rocket science to hand solder a piece of metal between the pads either. Actually a 0603 zero ohm resistor is almost the perfect size.

Comment: @mkeith They don't seem to have any matching parts. I've never heard of them either, do you know if they are a serious supplier?

Comment: <sigh> please do a bit of clicking around. You are the one who needs the part not me. https://topline.tv/drawings/pdf/sot/SOT23_jumper.pdf

Comment: The DC12 jumper code seems to be exactly what you are asking for. I don't know if they are a real supplier, though.

Comment: Problem is that we are talking really high volume here, so hand soldering is not excatly an option. Perhaps 0603 jumper could work, i need to check with production company if they are willing to do it. If someone have exact model of diode with common anode on pin 1 and 2, please tell me model, because i cannot find it

Comment: i did found that exact topline sot23 jumpers, but cannot find them as a supplier for the parts, thereofre im asking here. Sorry if i asked bad question, its my first question on this forum, still finding my way around :)

Comment: @mkeith Most excellent find!

Comment: Topline has a list of distributors, and I can find the product listed on the page of a German supplier. So they don't look like a complete scam or something. Contact them...

Comment: I am not sure if it is a bad question. I mean I don't think it is a bad question and I had a similar problem some time ago. But "shopping" questions are considered to be off-topic. And some might say that this is a shopping question. I would definitely recommend that you attempt to email or call topline using the contact information on their website. They should be able to quote you cost and lead-time immediately if they are a real supplier. There are a lot of Taiwanese and Chinese suppliers that don't distribute through Arrow/Mouser/digikey/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distance between the centers of the two pins you want to connect is 1.9 mm, a 0805 SMD 0Ω-resistor would fit quite well for solder stencil reflow (it being 2.0 mm long), or a 0603 resistor if you want to hand-solder/hot-air rework, as that leaves more "handspace".

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a resistor, or even a piece of wire. A PCB assembler could hand-solder either of these if the spacing is right for their resistor or the wire.